# How to return a subset of an integer array with minimal elements that yield a maximum sum?

Tags: c#, arrays, subset

I am partaking on an Amazon interview and they tasked us with this coding challenge, Given an integer array `arr` write code that will return the minimal subset of that array where the elements of the subset yield the higher value against the sum of the remaining subset. An example is the array `3,7,5,6,2`, the code needs to return either two subsets, the first one being `5,7` which yields a maximal value of `12` against the sum of the remaining subset `3,6,2` which yields a maximal value of `11`. The second one being `6,7` which will yield a maximal value of `13` against the remaining subset `3,5,2` which will yield a maximal value of `10`. I think my code is failing at the minimal array elements that yield a maximal value.
The code I have tried is below but its only passing only two of the thirteen test cases.
The test [page](https://www.hackerrank.com/test/63ek10mhil5/questions/24i33a0pf0l) is a demo assessment but serves as a preparation for an actual test that will come later, help me write this code correctly to return the correct output.

```
public static List<int> minimalHeaviestSetA(List<int> arr)
    {
        List<int> sol = new List<int>();List<int> sec= new List<int>();
        //try finding the two largest numbers in the array and add
        int max=0;
        foreach(int u in arr){
            if(u>max){
                max=u;
            }
        }
        //add the maximum element to the list
        
        //initialize the sum
        int sum=0;
        //remove the maximum element from the list
        arr.Remove(max);
        foreach(int p in arr){
            if((p+max)>sum){
                sum=p+max;
                sec.Clear();
                sec.Add(p);
            }
            
        }
        sol.Add(sec[0]);
        sol.Add(max);
        return sol;
        
    }
```

Some additional instruction from the site include

1. The intersection of subset A and B is null
2. The union of A and B returns the original array
3. The number of elements in subset A is minimal
4. The sum of subset A elements is greater than subset B elements

Comment: Should you consider sorting the array first?

Comment: The array sorting is done after you have the minimal subset, in increasing order

Comment: I would suggest first sorting the array (in descending order), then iteratively splitting it into two collections, moving the splitting point one index rightwards and comparing the sums of each collection for each iteration. The moment the first collection's sum is greater than the second collection's sum, you'll have A.

Comment: @AstridE., okay will give that a try

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 * Given an integer array nums of length n and an integer target, find three integers in nums such that the sum is closest to target.

    Return the sum of the three integers.
    
    You may assume that each input would have exactly one solution.
    
     
    
    Example 1:
    
    Input: nums = [-1,2,1,-4], target = 1
    Output: 2
    Explanation: The sum that is closest to the target is 2. (-1 + 2 + 1 = 2).
    Example 2:
    
    Input: nums = [0,0,0], target = 1
    Output: 0
     
    
    Constraints:
    
    3 <= nums.length <= 1000
    -1000 <= nums[i] <= 1000
    -104 <= target <= 104
```

*/

```
public class Tuples
{
    public int sum;
    public int[] Array;
    public int distance;
}
public class _3SumClosest
{
    public int[] input;

    public _3SumClosest()
    {
        input = new int[] { -1, 2, 1, -4 };
    }
    public int ThreeSumClosest(int[] nums, int target)
    {
        //Get comnbination of all indexes of Array
        double count = Math.Pow(2, nums.Length);
        var list = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.Length; i++)
            list.Add(i);
        List<int[]> combinations = new List<int[]>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= count - 1; i++)
        {
            string str = Convert.ToString(i, 2).PadLeft(nums.Length, '0');
            List<int> temp = new List<int>(); ;
            for (int j = 0; j < str.Length; j++)
            {
                if (str[j] == '1')
                {
                    temp.Add(list[j]);
                }
            }
            combinations.Add(temp.ToArray());
        }
        //filter combinations with 2sum, 3sum or nsum array combination. Dont filter if no requirement
        //if you want 3 number combination
        var tupleComb = combinations.Where(x => x.Length == 3);
        List<Tuples> tupleList = new List<Tuples>();
        foreach(var tuple in tupleComb)
        {
            var sum = nums[tuple[0]] + nums[tuple[1]] + nums[tuple[2]];
            Tuples tp = new Tuples();
            tp.sum = sum;
            tp.Array = new int[] { nums[tuple[0]], nums[tuple[1]], nums[tuple[2]] };
            tupleList.Add(tp);
        }

        var final = tupleList.Select(x => new Tuples() { sum = x.sum, Array = x.Array, distance = x.sum - target });
        return final.OrderBy(x => x.distance).FirstOrDefault().sum;
    }

}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Keep removing maximal elements from the list till the sum of elements in subset A return a value greater than the sum of the elements remaining in the original subset using a while loop, I used several test cases for testing the effectiveness of the code. There are functions to return the highest element and others to return the sum of elements in that list.

```
Console.WriteLine("Test Case 1");
int[] arr = new int[] { 9, 8, 7, 6 ,5,3};
List<int> soln = MinimalElements(arr.ToList());
if (soln != null)
{
    foreach (var VARIABLE in soln)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Test Case 2");
int[] arr1 = new int[] { 3,5,7,0,11};
List<int> soln1 = MinimalElements(arr1.ToList());
if (soln != null)
{
    foreach (var VARIABLE in soln1)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Test Case 3");
int[] arr2 = new int[]{0,9};
List<int> soln2 = MinimalElements(arr2.ToList());
if (soln2 != null)
{
    foreach (var VARIABLE in soln2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(VARIABLE);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Test Case 4");
int[] arr3 = new int[] { 0, 17, 6, 10, 2 };
List<int> soln3 = MinimalElements(arr3.ToList());
if (soln3 != null)
{
    foreach (var r in soln3)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(r);
    }
}
//pseudocode
//get the first element of the array and compare with the sum of the 
//remaining elements if its less than the sum of the remaining elements then
static List<int> MinimalElements(List<int> arr)
{
    //check if the array contains elements
    if (arr.Count() > 0)
    {
        //sort the array first
        arr.Sort();
        //create the return list
        List<int> result = new List<int>();
        //get the maximum of the original list and remove it
        int max = MaxInTheList(arr);
        //add the maximum to our list
        result.Add(max);
        //pop the element from the original collection
        arr.Remove(max);
        //loop through each list while comparing sum and keep adding elements until the sum of the 
        //resulting list is better than the elements removed from the original list
        while (sumList(result) < sumList(arr))
        {
            int mm = MaxInTheList(arr);
            //add the next biggest element to the array
            result.Add(mm);
            //keep reducing elements from arr
            arr.Remove(mm);
        }
        //return a sorted integer array to the calling function
        result.Sort();
        return result; 
    }
    else
    {
        //return an empty integer array
        return new List<int>();
    }
    
}
//define method to sum up all the elements of a list
static int sumList(List<int> arr)
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var s in arr)
    {
        sum += s;
    }

    return sum;
}
//first get the maximum integer of each list using a method
static int MaxInTheList(List<int> arr)
{
    int max = 0;
    foreach (int u in arr)
    {
        if (u > max)
        {
            max = u;
        }
    }
    return max;
}
```